# Target is not a JDK Root. Java executable was not found jdk 13.0.2 eclipse 2019

Tags: java, eclipse

I have reinstalled java, jdk and eclipse many times but i am still not able to add my jdk13 into my eclipse. 
 I downloaded the eclipse-java-2019-12-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg file
[This is my java (version 8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQawg.png)

[My JRE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNqiM.png)

[My JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QoD2.png)

[But yet this still occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgfqU.png)

Please help :'(((( I have no idea what went wrong when I followed guides and steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS the directory for Installed JREs is

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

(I am using the Oracle Java 13.0.2).